# Spring boot - Eclipelink scanning orm.xml

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink, spring-boot

I'm converting an existing application to spring boot, when I run the application using the created jar I get an exception when it scans and finds an orm.xml inside my entities jar (included as a dependency).

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException:
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@38cdedfd
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [UAccessPersistenceUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open root Jar file 'jar:file:everything-jar.jar'
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
                        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
                                at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)


Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [UAccessPersistenceUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open root Jar file 'jar:file:everything-jar.jar'
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1954)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1945)
                        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
                                at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:96)
                                        ... 46 common frames omitted
                                        Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException:
                                        Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [UAccessPersistenceUnit] failed.
                                        Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open root Jar file 'jar:file:everything-jar.jar'
                                                at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
                                                        ... 50 common frames omitted
```

This isn't using spring data, i'm building the datasources from a external properties file at the moment. It's the scanning that seems to cause issues.

This is spring boot 1.1.5-RELEASE with eclipselink 2.5.1

everything-jar.jar is a spring boot packed jar. With my compiles classes, the spring boot loader and the entities packaged in a jar. I've marked the dependency to be unpacked and it works, but it's not ideal.

This problem keeps coming up, now if I try to load persistence.xml from another jar it throws this same exception.

Comment: I think that your trouble could be Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open root Jar file 'jar:file:everything-jar.jar' can you give more information about this jar

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot to setup the entity manager or are you doing things yourself. I suggest to ditch your own properties file and the loading of it and use the Spring Boot default application.properties loading. Rename the properties you are using to the be able to bootstrap using spring boot (i.e. `spring.datasource.*` and try to let Spring Boot do its magic instead of yourself. Next you also might want to try the newly released 1.1.6 version, who knows. To be of more help can you post part of your configuration, the bootstrap class and the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a  lot of investigation it seems there are two parts to the problem here.

1. The spring boot loader supports urls that look something like this :
   jar:file:!/!/
2. Eclipselink generates urls for embedded orm.xml files like so 
   jar:jar:file:!/!/

I've got a fix in spring boot to make it better at opening the eclipselink URLs, but for an immediate fix we need to create a custom ArchiveFactoryImpl and override the createArchive method to return a custom JarInputStreamURLArchive when the protocol is jar.

In this custom class override the get entry as URL to check for a url with a protocol of jar that starts with jar and create a new URL from the file of the original (this cuts off the protocol part from the original url giving us jar:url instead of jar:url:url

```
public URL getEntryAsURL(String entryPath) throws IOException {
            URL entryUrl = super.getEntryAsURL(entryPath);

            if(entryUrl == null) {
                return null;
            }

            if("jar".equals(entryUrl.getProtocol()) && entryUrl.getFile().startsWith("jar:")) {
                //cut off the jar portions
                String file = entryUrl.getFile();
                return new URL(file);
            } else {
                return entryUrl;
            }
        }
```